# CocaPods Unable to find a target named

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have been trying for almost a day now , but my cocaPods isnt working for multiple projects. In my podfile one of the project Operator isnt found although they both are in same directory.
Thanks in advance. Here is my podfile. Please help me out the error im  getting is

```
[!] Unable to find a target named `WGOperator`
```

//PodeFile

```
workspace 'VisitorsLibrary'

xcodeproj 'WGCore/WGCore.xcodeproj'
xcodeproj 'DemoNoLib.xcodeproj'
xcodeproj 'WGOperators/WGOperator.xcodeproj'
target :WGCore do
platform :ios, '7.0'

 pod 'XMPPFramework', '~> 3.6.1'
 pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0.0'
 pod 'AFNetworking/NSURLConnection' ,'~> 2.0.0'
 pod 'FMDB', '~> 2.1'
 pod 'JSMessagesViewController', '~> 3.4.1'
 pod 'MRProgress', '~> 0.2'
    xcodeproj 'WGCore/WGCore.xcodeproj'
end

target :WGOperator do
platform :ios, '7.0'

 pod 'XMPPFramework', '~> 3.6.1'
 pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0.0'
 pod 'AFNetworking/NSURLConnection' ,'~> 2.0.0'
 pod 'FMDB', '~> 2.1'
 pod 'JSMessagesViewController', '~> 3.4.1'
 pod 'MRProgress', '~> 0.2'
    xcodeproj 'WGOperators/WGOperator.xcodeproj'
end

target :DemoNoLib do
platform :ios, '7.0'

 pod 'XMPPFramework', '~> 3.6.1'
 pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0.0'
 pod 'AFNetworking/NSURLConnection' ,'~> 2.0.0'
 pod 'FMDB', '~> 2.1'
 pod 'JSMessagesViewController', '~> 3.4.1'
 pod 'MRProgress', '~> 0.2'
    xcodeproj 'DemoNoLib.xcodeproj'
end

#target :WGOperator do
#   xcodeproj 'WGOperator/WGOperator'
#     # specific dependencies
#end
```

Comment: Do the target exist in Xcode we you open the xcproject ?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue. In my case this works but I'm not sure that it works correctly.

```
workspace 'PROJECT_NAME_WORKSPACE'


xcodeproj 'PROJECT_NAME-App/PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj'

target :PROJECT_NAME do
  xcodeproj 'PROJECT_NAME-App/PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj'
  pod 'Haneke', '~> 1.0'  

end


target :PROJECT_NAMESDK do
  xcodeproj 'PROJECT_NAME-SDK/PROJECT_NAME-SDK.xcodeproj'
  pod 'OHHTTPStubs'
end
```